# error in downloading a gif picture from url python

Tags: python, download, gif

I want to download on disk the gif image:

http://www.portaportese.it/telefono/es_2014043024395.gif

with all the codes I found out around for downloading pictures, I end up with a error in the final saved picture such as:

GIF image was truncated or incomplete.

in a few words the picture is not being saved correctly.

Is there anybody able to provide a correct solution which will download this picture on disk?

Any code returns an empty image.. I tried this:

```
import urllib2

picture_page = "http://www.portaportese.it/telefono/es_2014043024395.gif"
opener1 = urllib2.build_opener()
page1 = opener1.open(picture_page)
my_picture = page1.read()
filename = "my_image.gif"
fout = open(filename, "wb")
fout.write(my_picture)
fout.close()
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service. Please [edit] your question and post the code you are using, along with the **complete text** of any errors or tracebacks, and we can help you that way.

Comment: The webserver itself is returning a 0 byte file when you request that URL.

Comment: I added the code! The program doesn't arise errors, just the picture is not being saved and when attempting to open it we have... GIF image was truncated or incomplete...

Answer (score 0):

The problem does not lie with your Python code, the image that you are trying to download does not exist. If I use curl to place a request at that URL, you can see that no image is stored there.

```
~ ❯❯❯ curl -I http://www.portaportese.it/telefono/es_2014043024395.gif
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 07 Jul 2014 19:35:05 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.3 (Red Hat)
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
```

Compare that with this request to a known image source:

```
~ ❯❯❯ curl -I http://baconmockup.com/300/200
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 07 Jul 2014 19:35:42 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.2
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Length: 20564
Content-Disposition: inline; filename=brisket-300-200.jpg
Pragma: public
Cache-Control: public
Expires: Mon, 21 Jul 2014 19:35:43 GMT
Last-Modified: Mon, 20 Aug 2012 19:20:21 GMT
Vary: User-Agent
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

If you change the URL in your code to a good image source, then it will work perfectly well.

```
import urllib2

picture_page = "http://baconmockup.com/300/200"
opener1 = urllib2.build_opener()
page1 = opener1.open(picture_page)
my_picture = page1.read()
filename = "my_image.gif"
fout = open(filename, "wb")
fout.write(my_picture)
fout.close()
```

I just ran this, and was given a picture of some tasty brisket.

Comment: Thank your for the answer.. but unfortunatly browsers show the image in that path!

This is what I do not understand. The announce is: 

http://www.portaportese.it/rubriche/Immobiliare/Ville_e_appartamenti_%28Roma%29/Montemario-Trionfale/m-cortina-d-ampezzo-via-courmayer-0ID2014050018041?tipo=offerte&numero=-2&latstart=41.8966&lngstart=12.494&zoomstart=10#.U7r_p6bJW1F

in the html of this page, inspecting the gif of the phone number we see that the location is:


http://www.portaportese.it/telefono/es_2014050018041.gif 

but even all, python downloads nothing at this gif location.

Comment: @user3813581 After some inspection, I discovered that the server will not send the image without a proper Cookie in the header. I am not sure how to request a cookie from this site using Python.

Comment: using postman, the headers for this get request are:

Cache-Control →max-age=86400 Connection →close Content-Type →image/gif Date →Tue, 08 Jul 2014 08:58:42 GMT Expires →Tue, 08 Jul 2014 08:58:44 GMT Pragma →cache Server →Apache/2.2.3 (Red Hat) Transfer-Encoding →chunked